Why the construction of ring of sections of a bundle?
I am reading page 78, Theorem 4.2.15 of the book Galois Theories, by Francis Borceus and George Janelidze. He stated the following definitions and results.
For a commutative ring $A$ with identity, a regular ideal of $A$ is an ideal generated by idempotents. A maximal regular ideal is a proper regular ideal of $A$ that is maximal in the family of all proper regular ideals. Let $\operatorname{sp}(A)$ be the set of all maximal regular ideals of $A$. One defines a topology on $\operatorname{sp}(A)$, called the Pierce spectrum of $A$: The closed sets are $V(I)=\{M\in\operatorname{sp}(A):M\supset I\}$ for all regular ideals $I$ of $A$. Denote $\mathcal O(I) = \operatorname{sp}(A)\setminus V(I)$. Note that this topology is isomorphic to the prime spectrum of the ring of idempotents in $A$ with addition defined by $x\oplus y=x+y-2xy$ and the product same as in $A$. Define a map $$F:\coprod_{M}A/M \to \operatorname{sp}(A)$$by mapping every $r+M$ to $M$, where the first coproduct runs through all maximal regular ideals of $A$. For every open set $\mathcal O(I)$ of $\operatorname{sp}(A)$, the sections of $F$ on $\mathcal O(I)$ are all the maps $$s_{I}:\mathcal O(I)\to\coprod_{M}A/M$$such that $F\circ s_I$ is identity, or equivalently every $M\in\mathcal O(I)$ is mapped to some $r+M$ for some $r\in A$. Assign the final topology on $\coprod_M A/M$ among all such maps $s_I$, where $I$ runs through all regular ideals of $A$. Define $\operatorname{Sec}_U = \Gamma\left(\coprod_M A/M, F\right)\left(U\right)$ to be the set of all sections of $F$ on $U$. For every idempotent $e\in A$ define $$\varphi_e:A\to \operatorname{Sec}_{\mathcal O(e)}$$by mapping $r\in A$ to the section $s_{eA}^r:\mathcal O_e\to\coprod_{M}A/M$ defined by mapping $M\in \mathcal O_e$ to $r+M$. The book then shows that each of this $\varphi_e$ is a surjective ring homomorphism with kernel of $(1-e)A$, so the ring of sections on $\mathcal O(e)$ is isomorphic to $eA$, and in particular when $e=1$, the ring of continuous sections is isomorphic to $A$.
I found this very interesting, but felt very hard to grasp what is really happening in there. I noticed there is a similar construction in algebraic geometry called the structural sheaf, but I have no idea about sheaves and schemes.
Could anyone explain from a higher point of view what is happening in here, and possibly give a reference book to read along with this book? I found the next few sections a little too fancy for me.

This is covered in Johnstone's Stone spaces but I'm not sure reading that will help you understand it any better. This is one of those things where it is better to practice using it than to just think very hard about it in a vacuum.

I think the link should be removed because it is an illegal copy of the book.
